# Divide a word based on a hierarchy of rules

Tags: regex

Let's say a string can be made up of the characters a, b, or c.

Is it possible through a regular expression to group the characters of a string by rules - with the most **strict rules being applied first, followed by weaker rules?**

For example:

- Priority rule: identify "ba" appearing together in a string.
- All remaining characters will be their own groups.

Therefore, a string such as `abbadaabad` would group to:

a, b, ba, d, a, a, ba, d

My thinking is that once I can set up a two-level rule set, I could create a deeper ruleset with more refined rules.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In an [alternation rule](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html), the first matching expression wins.

This pattern will match `ba` if it is found, otherwise it will match individual characters:

```
ba|.
```

Here an example usage in Python:

```
>>> from re import findall
>>> s = 'abbadaabad'
>>> findall(r'ba|.', s)
['a', 'b', 'ba', 'd', 'a', 'a', 'ba', 'd']
```